# How can I apply a GradientBrush to multiple consecutive objects in XAML?

Tags: .net, xaml, .net-3.5, panel, gradient

I have a TextBlock and a Line sitting next to each other in their own exclusive StackPanel.

I need to spread my LinearGradientBrush across the two objects, rather than shading them individually.

My project currently looks like this:

http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/1268/seperategradients.png

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        SomeTextContent
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Blue" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Orange" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>

    <Line VerticalAlignment="Bottom" X2="100">
        <Line.Stroke>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Blue" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Orange" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Line.Stroke>
    </Line>

</StackPanel>
```

As shown, the gradient is applied to TextBlock seperately from the Line. I need to find a way to apply the gradient across the TextBlock and the Line in a single pass - as if they were the same object entirely. In this example, the text should be mostly blue and the line should be mostly orange.

Comment: Are you using WPF or Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF you can use a Visual Brush.

Add a brush resource to your window or control resources:

```
<Window.Resources>      
  <VisualBrush x:Key="stackPanel">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"> 
          SomeTextContent        
        </TextBlock>   
        <Line VerticalAlignment="Bottom" X2="100" Stroke="black"/>     
      </StackPanel>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
  </VisualBrush>
</Window.Resources>
```

Next, apply that brush to the opacitymask of a rectange, for example:

```
  <Rectangle OpacityMask="{DynamicResource stackPanel}">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1.0,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="1"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
     </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
```

You can turn the text into a path too, but you'll loose the ability to change the text than.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that text is not a vector and so cannot be combined with the line (any way that I know of).

I believe that it is possible to change text into a vector path in Expression Blend and then use that to create a clipping path over the gradient. Or, using the text vector path like you would do with your line, use a background colour unrestricted-height border and transparent fill on the vector itself.

Seems like a lot of trouble to go to. Have you thought about using a third colour to merge the two? For example text block fade from Blue to Orange, then on the line Orange to the background colour. You might be able to get a similar effect for a lot less effort.